# Find duplicates in a given Array - Index 5 out of bounds for length 4 when I'm doing foldLeft in Scala

Tags: scala, exception, syntax

I only try to find duplicates in a given array. My code is:

```
 def findDuplicates(nums: Array[Int]): List[Int] = {
nums.map(transformValues(nums)).toList

}

def transformValues(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    nums.foldLeft(Array[Int]())((accumValue, nextEl) => {
      if (nums.tail.contains(nextEl)) accumValue :+ nextEl
      else accumValue
    })
  }

  val arr = Array(5, 1, 1, 1, 2)
  println(findDuplicates(arr))
```

The result should be Array(1, 1, 1), but instead I receive an exception, I also tried to debug and found out that in the row nums.map(transformValues(nums)).toList it returns the initial array.
Could someone help me to understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `map` operation is likely not what you expect.

It's the same as:

```scala
nums.map(x => transformValues(nums)(x))
```

Meaning you're calling `transformValues` and retrieving the `x`-th item of the response but there's no guarantee it exists.

Answer (score 1):

In `nums.map(transformValues(nums))` you're doing something weird.

If `nums` is `Array(a, b, c, ...)` then `nums.map(f)` is `Array(f(a), f(b), f(c), ...)`.

`nums.map(transformValues(nums))` is `nums.map(transformValues(nums).apply(_))` i.e. `Array(transformValues(nums).apply(a), transformValues(nums).apply(b), transformValues(nums).apply(c), ...)`.

`transformValues(nums).apply(a)` means find the `a`th element (starting from 0) of the array `transformValues(nums)`. But `a=5` and there is no 5th element in your array `transformValues(nums)`.